# Expanded legend over 2 subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

How can I have the same legend appear over 2 subplots and make it expanded over the 2. Does any one know, if I have to precise the y label for each subplot separately if it is the same (The plot is for a scientific paper) ? I know that the latter question has nothing to do with computing, but if any one knows the answer, I would appreciate it.

For the placement of the legend I use:

```
        ax[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1., .102), loc=3,
               ncol= 4, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0)
```

[image: plots]

Comment: Is this a matplolib question?

Comment: yes it is. Does is it not suit this forum?

Comment: It's suitable. It might receive more answers with a matplotlib tag. I'll add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the legend stretch across both subplots, you need to adjust the coordinates given to `bbox_to_anchor`. Using `2.2` for the width (the third argument) covers 2x the width of the plot plus the spacing in between subplots. (If you have a different spacing than the default, like `f.tightlayout()`, this value will need adjusted.)

Here's a simple working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)
x2 = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0)

y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)
y2 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x2)

f,ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].plot(x1, y1, 'ko-', label='Damped')
ax[0].plot(x2, y2, 'r.-', label='Undamped')
ax[1].plot(x1, y1, 'ko-', label='Damped')
ax[1].plot(x2, y2, 'r.-', label='Undamped')

ax[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 2.2, .102), loc=3,
               ncol=4, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0)

plt.show()
```

The result is this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

To stretch the legend across all subplots in a figure, you may semi-automate the legend placement. Using the `subplotpars` from the figure allows to find the spacings used, such that those spacings can directly be used in the `bbox_to_anchor` argument. This requires to have the legend transform set to the figure transform via the `bbox_transform` argument. The only parameters you need to specify manually are then the spacing between the axes and the legend (0.02 in below example) and the height of the legend (0.05 in below example), both in units of figure height.

```
s = fig.subplotpars
bb=[s.left, s.top+0.02, s.right-s.left, 0.05 ]
leg = axes[0].legend(..., bbox_to_anchor=bb, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0,
                     bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)
```

A full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(10,8), axis=0)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

for i in range(a.shape[1]):
    axes[i//4].plot(a[:,i], marker="s", label="Label {}".format(i))

s = fig.subplotpars
bb=[s.left, s.top+0.02, s.right-s.left, 0.05 ]
leg = axes[0].legend(loc=8, bbox_to_anchor=bb, ncol= 4, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0,
                bbox_transform=fig.transFigure, fancybox=False, edgecolor="k")
leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(72./fig.dpi)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As to whether you need one or two legends in a scientific paper, this is completely dependend on the style of the paper. I would guess that using a single legend like here is fine. However journals mostly require you to mark each subplot with a small letter, like `a` and `b` or  `(a)` and `(b)`.